# Prolog HMM Tagger, syntax error, questionable program structure

Tags: syntax, prolog

I am attempting to implement an HMM tagger in Prolog by following along with a seemingly very simple tutorial, found [here](http://www.ling.gu.se/~lager/Spaghetti/spaghetti.html).

As a complete novice to Prolog I am having trouble getting the results described therein.

Thus far, I've written the data, i.e. all of the 
`outprob(a,det,0.300).` and `transprob(start,det,0.30).` to a file, furthermore I've included the HMM function further down in the same file, i.e.

```
most_probable_sequence(Words,Ss) :-
    findall(PS,sequence(Words,1-[start],PS)PSs),
    max_key(PSs,P-Ss1),
    reverse(Ss1,[start|Ss]).

sequence([],PSs,PSs).
sequence([Word|Words],P1-[S1|Ss],PSs) :-
    outprob(Word,S2,Po),
    transprob(S1,S2,Pt),
    P2 is Po*Pt*P1,
    sequence(Words,P2-[S2,S1|Ss],PSs).
```

I loaded the file into Prolog using the `['filename.pl'].` command, and I received the following error message:

```
:40:42: Syntax error: Operator expected
```

Is that in reference to lines 40 and 42?

If so, that would correspond to lines which specify `findall(PS,sequence(Words,1-[start],PS)PSs),` and `reverse(Ss1,[start|Ss]).`

My intuition is that I need to define a function for `findall()` and `reverse()` on my own, perhaps once again further down in the same file. Is that correct?

Once this issue is resolved, is it true that I would find results by typing the following command at the Prolog interface:

```
?- most_probable_sequence([he,can,can,a,can],Sequence).
```

PS The included link will show the Viterbi tagger, which is ostensibly very similar to the HMM I'm trying to implement, though to be exact the HMM is located on the bottom of that page under the subsection 'More...' following the link which says "There is a short paper describing the implementation in more detail".

Comment: a typo. Correct to `findall(PS,sequence(Words,1-[start],PS),PSs),`

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. Is there a good IDE for Prolog that would run on Linux?

I corrected that error. Now I'm receiving the warning message ':39: Singleton variables: [P]', I tried to run the code with that prompt I specified in my original question and it generated an Exception. More specifically 'Exception: (7) max_key([5.10300000000002e-13-[aux, det... etc.' Do you know what might be causing that, and what I might do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CapelliC pointed out, the error was a typo, but in fact the problem with that code is more insidious than I at first imagined.

Now, when running the code, with the corrected typo, an error is generated such that it says:

```
ERROR: most_probable_sequence/2: Undefined procedure: max_key/2
```

Which is followed by

```
Exception: (7) max_key([5.103000000002e-13-[aux, det, aux, aux, pron
```

And so on, with a series of very large numbers and then an associated list of tags.

Is it right to say that the first error is having to do with the amount of inputs fed to the most_probable_sequence() function?

What might be the cause of the exception? The size of those numbers?

*There is also a warning generated when I first load in the file, which says:

```
:39:
Singleton variables: [P]
```

Is it possible that this has something to do with the trouble?

Comment: P should be PS, I guess. max_key/2 is undefined, don't know if it could be a builtin of the Prolog used to develop the original code. Seems improbable...

Comment: I've not seen any documentation for max_key, but I'm finding referenced to something called max_assoc, though I just tried that and it didn't work. Maybe there's another work around to that, I guess what it's trying to do is store the probability value for each set of tags, does that seem right? So we can later choose the highest probability one.

Comment: yes, I was trying to recover the definition... maybe I'll post later

Answer (score 1):

not sure the outcome make sense (but it seems to do)

```
?- most_probable_hmm_path([he,can,can,a,can],Sequence).
Sequence = [pron, aux, v, det, n].
```

it's the result of

```
outprob(a,det,0.300).
outprob(can,aux,0.010).
outprob(can,v,0.005).
outprob(can,n,0.001).
outprob(he,pron,0.070).

transprob(start,det,0.30).          transprob(v,det,0.36).
transprob(start,aux,0.20).          transprob(v,aux,0.01).
transprob(start,v,0.10).            transprob(v,v,0.01).
transprob(start,n,0.10).            transprob(v,n,0.26).
transprob(start,pron,0.30).         transprob(v,pron,0.36).
transprob(det,det,0.20).            transprob(n,det,0.01).
transprob(det,aux,0.01).            transprob(n,aux,0.25).
transprob(det,v,0.01).              transprob(n,v,0.39).
transprob(det,n,0.77).              transprob(n,n,0.34).
transprob(det,pron,0.01).           transprob(n,pron,0.01).
transprob(aux,det,0.18).            transprob(pron,det,0.01).
transprob(aux,aux,0.10).            transprob(pron,aux,0.45).
transprob(aux,v,0.50).              transprob(pron,v,0.52).
transprob(aux,n,0.01).              transprob(pron,n,0.01).
transprob(aux,pron,0.21).           transprob(pron,pron,0.01).

most_probable_hmm_path(Words,Path) :-
      probable_paths(Words,[1-[start]],PPaths),
      keymax(PPaths,_P-Path1),
      reverse(Path1,[start|Path]).

probable_paths([],PPaths,PPaths).
probable_paths([Word|Words],PPaths0,PPaths) :-
      findall(PPath,
          (outprob(Word,Tag2,PL),
          findall(P2-[Tag2,Tag1|Tags],
              (member(P1-[Tag1|Tags],PPaths0),
              transprob(Tag1,Tag2,PT), 
              P2 is PL*PT*P1),
          AllPaths),
          keymax(AllPaths,PPath)),
      PPaths1),
      probable_paths(Words,PPaths1,PPaths).

keymax(AllPaths,U-V) :-
    aggregate(max(N,P), member(N-P,AllPaths), max(U,V)).
```

Comment: I'll be damned. You're a sun bronzed greek God if I ever saw one. 

If you wouldn't mind, could you just kind of walk me through the way you approached that problem? I'm curious to know what was going on in you're head that enabled you to find a solution like that.

Comment: I followed the link to Torbjorn' page, grabbed the code, added a simple minded maxkey/2... Of course, I use SWI-Prolog, that provides an IDE and debugging tools, but here I simply posted the first result obtained, no need to debug or understand the code.

Comment: Do you know how I could print the output at various stages to get a better sense of how that code works? I tried using { printRowValues(keymax, N) :- 
    N is 1 + len(keymax). 
} 
But that didn't work.

Comment: There is library(debug). You add debug(hmm, 'your message') and then enable the output in console with debug(hmm). When I'm too lazy, I use writeln/1. But anyway you should evaluate expressions before calling, like `length(Keys,N),M is N+1,writeln(m:M),` The algorithm is well explained in the [paper.ps](http://www.ling.gu.se/~lager/Spaghetti/spaghetti.ps).